# Repeating partitioner steps causing huge performance delay

Tags: java, spring-batch

Below is my job flow.

Step 1 : Download large files – more than 5 GB
Step 2 :Split file in small file

Step 3 : process file – process split files using partitioner and taskExecutor

Repeat step 1 to 3  till some condition is satisfied – normally  more than 10k repetitions

When batch start performances is very good. But as time progress  performances degrades.
**Note –** processing of data is not bottleneck

I am suspecting  Repeating partitioner steps is creating new threads for each repetition.

Below are my config

```
@Bean
public Job myjob(JobBuilderFactory jobs) throws Exception {
    return jobs.get("myjob")                
            .start(DownloadStep())
            .next(master()).on(CONTINUE_CONDITION .next(DownloadStep())
            .next(master()).on(STOP_CONDITION).to(cleanUpStep())                
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public Partitioner partitioner() {
    MultiResourcePartitioner multiResourcePartitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
    ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(cl);
    Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("file:" some file path);       
    multiResourcePartitioner.setResources(resources);
    multiResourcePartitioner.partition(10);     
    return multiResourcePartitioner;
}


@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();     
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(30);        
    return taskExecutor;
}   

@Bean
@Qualifier("master")
public Step master() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("master")
            .partitioner(process())
            .partitioner("process",partitioner) 
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())           
            .build();
}
```

**Update  As suggested by  Michael Minella  I updated Spring Batch version to 4.0.0.RC1 But there is no improvement in performance**

After 150+ repetitions batch is taking more than 15+ minutes to created partition steps. I am creating 16 partition for each file.

```
2017-12-05 17:00:51,660  INFO  [THREAD ID=main] XXXXXConfiguration. - Resource files: 16
2017-12-05 17:11:20,923  INFO   [THREAD ID=taskExecutor-17]  XXXProcessor. - XXXXListener beforeStep StepExecution: id=841, version=1, name=XXXStep:partition14, st
atus=STARTED, exitStatus=EXECUTING, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=0, rollbackCount=0
```

Comment: I just committed a fix that should help with this.  The issue is as the collection of `StepExecution` instances grows, the performance of the collection degrades.  Grab the 4.0.0.RC1 I just released today and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Michael for checking this. will try this with new version.  one more point . is there any relation between  number of partition, number of threads and number of split files ? what will be the ideal ratio ?

Comment: @MichaelMinella -updated the version but no improvement. Added some info in quotation. Could you please check ? Is there any way we can cleanup  old StepExecutions

Comment: Have you done any profiling on this to see what the bottle neck is?

Comment: How are you transferring data from step 1 to step 3 ?

Comment: what information do you want to pass?